# multiple values to a key in tcl array

Tags: tcl, associative-array

Ho do I specify multiple values to a key in Tcl associative array?

```
set A(a) val1
set A(a) val2
```

This is overriding the value and, on printing, I get the last value. How to store and to retrieve both of them?

Answer (score 2):

You could store the values in a list, and store that list into the array:

```
set A(a) [list val1]
lappend A(a) val2
puts $A(a)
# val1 val2
```

Comment: This is the standard way to do this, and that's true across many languages (after allowing for syntax and so on).

Comment: Note: There is no need to use a different approach for the first and subsequent elements. You can use `lappend` for all. The `lappend` command will behave the same as the `set`/`list` combination shown in the code above if the array element does not exist.